# How to compile and package maven gwt project in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: maven, tomcat, gwt, deployment, intellij-idea

I'm beginning with maven and have created `gwt` simple example like `stockWatcher`.
To compile and package project into `war` I use three operations:

1. LifeCycle 'Compile'
2. then go to command line and run 'mvn gwt:compile'
3. LifeCycle 'Package'

After that I copy `war` file into `Apache Tomcat`.
Plese help me to automate these steps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have `gwt:compile` wired up in Maven, then `mvn package` (possibly invoked from the IDE through *LifeCycle 'Package'*) should be enough to produce the WAR you're after: in the linear lifecycle that Maven uses, the `package` phase implies the `compile` and `prepare-package` phases (the latter to which the `gwt:compile` goal is bound by default).

Comment: Thank you. But my `compile` step doesn't invoke `gwt:compile` and I have no `prepare-package` in my `Lifecycle`. I have made new `Run configuration` for `package` step and added `clean` `compile` `gwt:compile` goals to `Before launch`. And it works.

Comment: Do you have an `<execution>` with `<goal>compile</goal>` in your `pom.xml` for the gwt-maven-plugin? If not, then add it; then invoking the `package` lifecycle phase should Just Work™.